# Errors when uploading images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website write code as WordPress but when upload image not rewrite, not show home index
I have using fix error `.htaccess` file but not sucsess.

http://maybomchim.net/

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask